# windows crash with a blue screen and differents stopcode

Tags: windows-10, crash

My pc keeps crashing with a blue screen showing different stopcodes

it's a xiaomi mi notebook 13 from 2016 :

- CPU : intel core i5-6200U
- RAM : 8Go DDR4 2133 MHz
- GPU : intel HD graphics 520 + NVIDIA GeForce 940MX 1Go GDDR5
- SSD : NVMe 256Go Samsung PM951

the pc was working fine 4 years ago, it then wasn't used for a long time

The stopcodes so far are :

```
SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
```

I basically only used internet on it the last two weeks since the blue screen are happening

I tried to reinstall a clean windows 10, then i reseted the bios parameters, and i tried to install linux but it stoped during installation with error "ubi-partman failed with exit code 141"

i wonder if there is something else i can try with the softwares, and then what to try with hardwares that wouldn't cost me much ? Is there a way to isolate different hardwares components to figure out wich one crashes ?

Comment: You installed something that caused this, a software or a driver most likely. Re-install Wimdows 10 with the latest ISO by formatting the hard drive. If it's a software problem it will be OK. Otherwise it's a hardware problem. Try removing the external video card. Some suggest the AHCI option in the BIOS is the problem. It's.probably the video card or HDD(SSD).

Comment: @CFCBazar_com did you not read that this is a laptop?  Certainly can't be troubleshot by removing the video card.  HDDs don't *usually* cause blue screens (but the connectors/cables do).

Comment: Have you tried running the laptop from a LIVE USB stick for a while to see if it works when the SSD isn't getting accessed?  Memory test?  Removed and reseated the memory.. then the SSD (if you must). ? You will need to figure out ways to isolate each component.. even the network if you can find a USB network adapter.. etc etc  Also, I GOOGLED your exact error and see lots of possible solutions.

Comment: thank you @SeñorCMasMas your comment is helpful i will try all that. I did googled my pbm but the answers where not as clear as yours about hardwares, most of the times it was about external hardwares for a desktop computer, like keyboard or mouse. It's possible i filtered answer in my mind since there is a lot of new informations for me.